# default priority value of _main() thread in windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading

I have a main program (C language)in visual studio 2005 which creates lot of threads.I have given pririty levels for them manually.But my program starts execution from _main() right. It is also a thread correct?
Then i want to know the default priority of that main thread(NORMAL/ABOVE NORMAL /HIGHEST).

Also can anybody please explain the exact difference between process and thread in windows?

Regards,
jacK

Comment: Sheesh, have some patience.  You waited a whole 4 minutes for an answer!

Comment: A process is essentially a collection of threads, where main() is called by the RTL startup code within the first (main) thread that is automatically created by the OS.  The main thread can then create additional threads as needed.  When the main thread terminates, the process terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just start as normal, unless you were to change it?

I mean, I am assuming you are changing the priority in the threads to change the overall program's behavior in some way -- if the default priority for the main thread were anything other than normal, what behavior would you expect the program to have? Does it do anything that would suggest it isn't normal?

Comment: thanks Myers.
But when am running the program ,the main thread ie __tmainCRTStartup thread showes NORMAL pririty...

I am simualating an OS to be run in windows by replacing the platform dependent codes with curresponding windows functionalities.

Comment: well, I'm not sure why windows would start a thread with another priority unless you explicitly told it to.

Comment: thanks. am also a s/w developer exclusively researching on C language.